# php's .user.ini with nginx and subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, ini

## Setup

I have installed nginx 1.2.2 and PHP 5.4.4. I have configured PHP with nginx running as FastCGI.

nginx config snippet:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           E:/Websites/localhost;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  E:/Websites/localhost/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I have a number of local virtual sites running on same system. To customize each ones requirements I have created .user.ini file in each sites root folder which as per the PHP documentation should be applicable on sub folders also.

Please note this is a development environment and not live. So I have flexibility to customize a number of things.

## Problem

When I access any site from the browser it works fine unless I do not dive into some sub folder. It seems that .user.ini does not work in sub directories - at least in my configuration.

As per PHP document (http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php):

> In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each
>   directory, **starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and
>   working its way up to the current document root**

## SOS

Has anyone configured .user.ini under nginx - request you to please help me out.

Note: Someone reported a bug in 2009: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50374

## More Information (EDIT)

PHPInfo() says (in root as well as in sub folders):
* Server API: *CGI/FastCGI*
* user_ini.filename: *.user.ini* (local as well as master)

php_sapi_name() says *cgi-fcgi*

These values are present in phpinfo() from root folder and sub directories. So there is no difference in PHPInfo().

Further confirmation that it is running as **CGI/FastCGI** is that root folder is taking configurations from **.user.ini** but not sub folders.

```
// .user.ini
auto_prepend_file = "E:\Websites\localhost\user.ini.php"
```

and

```
// user.ini.php
<?php
printf('Hi from: %s', __FILE__);
?>
```

This may actually be a bug but has anyone configured PHP with nginx in this way and did not faced the problem. Requesting to please share version numbers and platform in this case.

Comment: Yes Bruni it looks like it is still a bug after being reported more then 2 years ago. But I am resting my hopes on nginx users who may have encountered same problem.

Comment: It is not a bug. See my post below.

Answer (score 1):

You only partially quoted the PHP docs you linked to. It also says `These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI`.

I suspect you are not using the CGI/FastCGI SAPI but some other SAPI ... the PHP-FPM SAPI perhaps?

As you may have figured from the above, running FastCGI is not equivalent to using the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. You can also run FastCGI using other SAPIs such as PHP-FPM.

BTW SAPI = Server API. You can look for yours in a phpinfo file.

Comment: Not sure if there is some misconfiguration or it is just a bug. But **php_sapi_name()** return **cgi-fcgi** and furthermore it works only in root folder but not in sub directories.

Comment: The SAPI for which this works is called `CGI/FastCGI`. Look in a phpinfo file for your precise one and not the php_sapi_name() output. Since you most likely using php-fpm, you can try to use the instructions by showerheadsuk at hotmail dot com on your linked documentation page.

Comment: BTW. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965807/how-do-i-get-php-5-3-8-to-read-a-user-ini-file

Comment: have added some code and phpinfo() values in my question. hope this helps to simplify the problem. phpinfo() also says: Server API: CGI/FastCGI.

Comment: Hi. You've still not said how you are actually running PHP. I.E., whether you are using PHP-FPM or not and if not, how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a much bigger issue then just nginx, but a permanent solution is available. The alternative ini_set method of adding directive options has significant limitations so it is not really a good long term solution. Thanks.
http://www.ait-pro.com/aitpro-blog/4349/misc-projects/wordpress-tips-tricks-fixes/php5-3-x-php5-4-x-user-ini-file-does-not-work-known-php5-3-x-user-ini-fastcgi-wordpress-zend-issue/

Comment: You must disclose affiliation with external sites.

Comment: @BeauGrantham - I looked through Stackoverflow help and FAQ and did not find any help info on "disclose affiliation with external sites". Can you clarify exactly what the rule is for this? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a SO rule, it's a general ethics rule common to most professions where community integrity and trust is critical to trusting solutions and advice in those professional settings (such as ours) - https://standards.ieee.org/faqs/affiliation.html

Comment: If you're reading this solution after 2020, then be warned that you shouldn't be using PHP 5.X any longer — it's been deprecated for æons.