# where to set max_post_size in the php:fpm docker image

Tags: php, docker, fpm

A php application executing inside a docker container

```
docker run -d -v "./app:/app" php:fpm
```

complains that the default value of post_max_size (8MB) is too small and I should increase it to 32MB.

Problem is, there is no php.ini in that docker image:

```
# ls -R /usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/etc/:
pear.conf  php  php-fpm.conf  php-fpm.conf.default  php-fpm.d

/usr/local/etc/php:
conf.d

/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:
docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini  docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini  docker-php-ext-sodium.ini

/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d:
docker.conf  www.conf  www.conf.default  zz-docker.conf
```

When I append `post_max_size = 32M` to any of the files under /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d, then the container stops during startup with error message

```
[22-Aug-2018 01:38:09] ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:424] unknown entry 'post_max_size'
[22-Aug-2018 01:38:09] ERROR: Unable to include /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf from /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf at line 424
[22-Aug-2018 01:38:09] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf'
[22-Aug-2018 01:38:09] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

When I create a new file `/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini` with content

```
post_max_size = 32M
```

then it has no effect. Where should I set this value when using this docker image php:fpm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution that worked for me was to set the container's environment variable [PHPRC](http://php.net/configuration.file) to the path of a directory where I placed a `php.ini` file containing the required setting.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to [`.user.ini` files](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php)

> Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a per-directory basis. These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI

You should be able to drop a file in your project at `./app/.user.ini` with

```
post_max_size = 32M
```

Comment: Thank you for this introduction. Placing a file named .user.ini into the documentroot did not have the desired effect, unfortunately. Even after restarting the docker container, the application still complained about a too low post_max_size value.

Comment: How odd. I'll have to try it out myself now

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372798 seems to suggest that php-fpm is something different from the "CGI/FastCGI SAPI" that you quoted.

Comment: The "F" in "FPM" stands for "FastCGI" so I really thought it would work. Other articles seem to indicate it should work just fine.